# ¿Qué significa "quoniam igitur"? / What's the meaning of "quoniam igitur"?

Tags: grammar-choice, meaning, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

En la pagina 262, linea 16, de *Lingua latina per se illustrata*, la linea empieza con

> Quoniam igitur ...

Según el diccionario ilustrado Vox, *quoniam* significa *puesto que* o *después que*, y *igitur* significa *así pues*. Lo que haría que la traducción a verbatim de *quoniam igitur* sea *puesto que así pues*,  pero ne tiene ningún sentido. Así que, que significa *quoniam igitur*?

---

**English translation:**

On page 262, line 16, of *Lingua latina per se illustrata*, the line begins with

> Quoniam igitur ...

According to Latin-Spanish dictionary *Vox ilustrado*, *quoniam* means *puesto que* or *después que*, and *igitur* means *así pues*. That would translate *quoniam igitur* verbatim in Spanish as  *puesto que así pues*,  but it hasn't any sense. So, what does  *quoniam igitur* mean?

Comment: Are questions in Spanish (or any other non-classical language, for that matter) allowed? I'm not sure if this merits a Meta question

Comment: I think the question answers itself if you change the word order: "así pues, puesto que..." (English: "and so, given that...") But you'd need to give more context for the original quote.

Comment: @brianpck Quoniam igitur propter vim atque multitūdinem
praedōnum nē mare Tuscum quidem tutum erat, pa­
rum frūmentl ex Siciliā et ex Āfricā Rōmam advehēbā­
tur.

Comment: @brianpck Suena también a sinsentido en español.

Comment: @brianpck That'd be a very reasonable meta question. I tried to look it up and it seems we don't have a discussion or policy about that. I have thoughts but I'd rather not discuss general matters here in comments.

Comment: Sorry, @Dolphínus: I don't think it's a good idea to create new tags in Spanish.

Comment: @Charo I am sure I am no the one you want or should to apologize.

Comment: I fully agree with @Charo: We should not have tags in Spanish, not even synonyms. Our main operating language is English and a far second is Latin. All other languages can play a minor role at best. If there's a need to discuss details, take it to [meta].

Answer (score 2):

The complete sentence is

> Quoniam igitur propter vim atque multitūdinem praedōnum nē mare Tuscum quidem tutum erat, parum frūmentī ex Siciliā et ex Āfricā Rōmam advehēbātur.

As you can see in Lewis and Short, [*igitur*](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/igitur) means "then", "therefore", that is, introduces a consequence. The other conjunction, [*quoniam*](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/quoniam), means "since", "because", i.e., introduces a reason. We find these two conjunctions because two relations cause-consequence are present in the text.

This is the first one. Many maritime cities had been conquered by pirates, pirates also attacked the ports of Italy.  As a consequence, everything stated by the above sentence happened. This "as a consequence" is conveyed by *igitur*.

This is the second one. Not even the Tuscan sea was safe because there were a large number of pirates and they had a lot of power. This "because" is expressed with *quoniam*.

Comment: Then *quoniam* is not a plonasm with *propter*?

Comment: @Dolphínus:   En español sería algo así: "puesto que a causa de la potencia y la gran cantidad de piratas ni siquiera el mar Toscano era seguro" (*quoniam* = "puesto que", *propter* = "a causa de").

Comment: poder*, no potencia